# How do I define a Windows only GVim configuration in my .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I don't have a `.gvimrc` file *(and I don't want it to be)* and I believe in single .vimrc file. I use `if has("gui_running")` method to define GVim configurations.

I have recently installed GVim on Windows *(first time installed on Windows)* and I don't like default font. After a few clicks I found `Lucida Console` of size `10` looks pretty there.

But the problem is I can't define font configuration anywhere in the file (it should be in *`gui_running`* section). Even in that section I can't define anywhere, I need a Windows only condition there. So, how can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from `gui_running` you can test for `has("gui_win32")`.

Answer (score 0):

The config setting is 'guifont'.